# Zip code validator - reject zip code

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with code to reject a zip code if the first 2 digits are 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95 and 96.

Does anyone have any guidance?  I have this for validation, but need to modify it.

```
$("[name='shipping_zip']").blur(function() {  
var cleanInputZip = ($("[name='shipping_zip']").val().replace(/\s/g, ""));
var filter1 = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/;
//alert(cleanInputEmail);
if (filter1.test(cleanInputZip)) {
//alert(cleanInputEmail);
$(".example11").empty();
}
else {
$("[name='shipping_zip']").val('');
$(".example11").empty();
$("[name='shipping_zip']").after('<div style="float:right;" class="example11"><b><font color="red">Invalid Zip Code  </font></b>' + cleanInputZip +'</div>');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help you

```js
blacklist = ["90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96"];

function isValid(zip) {
  return zip.length > 3 && blacklist.indexOf(zip.slice(0,2)) < 0; 
}

document.getElementById("shipping_zip").addEventListener('blur', function(e){
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = isValid(e.target.value) ? "" : "Invalid zip" ; 
});
```

```html
<input name="shipping_zip" id="shipping_zip">
<div id="message">
</div>
```